# Django count using raw query

Tags: python, django

I'm having a trouble on how can I count query in Django raw using this query below. This is what should  looks like.I just want to count number of paid. It would be great if anybody could help me thanks in advance!.
[image]

```
rpts_paid_count.append(p.paid).count()  #Error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

> What I've tried in Django

```
 rpts_paid_count = []
 blank = ""
 for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM app_person WHERE paid_by != %s GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid', [blank]):
     rpts_paid_count.append(p.paid).count() #Error Part
  
 results = {'rpts_paid_count':rpts_paid_count}
 return JsonResponse(results)
```

Comment: Why do you need a raw query, this is a simple `annotate`.

Comment: It is also quite "odd" that you store this in a `person` table. Normally that would store data about *person*s, not about the (paid) invoices. By storing the names of the people, etc. it makes lookups, filtering, etc. less efficient.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your response, but  honestly I've been struggling convert it to Django format that's why I decide to use raw, just need help

Comment: the main problem is *not* the query, but simply mismodeling. A table named `person` should *not* store invoice data. You store that in a different model: right now it will create a *huge* and *unresponsive* database with a lot of data duplication, which will also easily result in "corrupt" data: for example if you later rename the person, then it will be hard to find all references to that person and update these accordingly.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your great idea, Still I don't know how to improve this  and still can't relate though. Im stuck with this module and Im out of options

Comment: you should create another model that specifies the invoices, with `ForeignKey`s to the `Person`, this deduplicates, makes the database more compact, and will optimize performance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but it is possible to get the count of my paid based of the current code above? `rpts_paid_count.append(p.paid).count() `